# Install vncserver on RedHat 6.3 using a CenOS/Fedora yum repo

Tags: redhat, yum, vnc-server

Can anyone tell me how to configure a CentOS/Fedora yum repo to install vncserver on RedHat 6.3

Answer (score 1):

- Now install few required packages for vnc-server:

`# yum install pixman pixman-devel libXfont`

- After installing required packages, lets install vnc-server in your system. vnc-server is available under default yum repositories.

`# yum install vnc-server`

- On CentOS/RHEL 6, you will see that tigervnc-server package will be installed.
- Create user1 and set password and Now set the vnc password for all accounts need to connect through vnc.

`su - user1`

`vncpasswd`

- Now edit /etc/sysconfig/vncservers configuration file and add the following to the end of the file.

`VNCSERVERS="1:user1" 
 VNCSERVERARGS[1]="-geometry 800x600"
 VNCSERVERARGS[2]="-geometry 1024x768"`

Where VNCSERVERS is the list of users need to connect, VNCSERVERARGS defined the screen size. Like user1 have a 800×600 screen, and user2 have 1024×768 screen size on his client.

- Now start vnc-server service using following command and check the output

`service vncserver start`

- To access from remote Linux system use following command.

`# vncviewer 192.168.1.11:1`

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is run the following command

> yum install tigervnc -y

When you are installing tigervnc, vnc-server will install along with it.

```
  yum whatprovides vnc-server
tigervnc-server-1.1.0-5.el6.x86_64 : A TigerVNC server
Repo        : base
Matched from:
Other       : vnc-server
```

Base repo is inbuilt for redhat. Please let me know if that helped you. :)

Comment: I got stucked at repos. Downvote is because is try it and doesn't work using a modified RedHat called AMI from amazon. Maybe only is not working on such EC2... Are you sure about instructions? I put finally a Ubuntu server because is based on Debian and cannot put the Debian in.

Comment: A down vote doesn't concerns me, It is your right to put in case if you finds the post not useful. No issues :) Normally vnc-server comes with CentOS base repository. Make sure that your base repository is enabled. If you finds difficult to install VNC server in debian or Ububtu, Let me know. I can  help you. Or PM or chat with me. Yum is just a method, There are must be plenty of other methods too... #erm3nda Have a good day :)

Comment: Ups. Add a little editing on post to quit my down, even if doesn't concern you. I have no prob with vnc. Usually i use apt for all, but on the RedHat i tried was the hell, surelly because that you say, the base repo. Regards :)

Comment: lol :) happy to see that you are managed to install VNC with the base repo. you can find it at _/etc/yum.repos.d_ See you around #erm3nda :)